# Can I convert a bunch of boolean columns to a single bitmap in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, boolean, bit-manipulation

I'd like to convert a query such as:

```
SELECT BoolA, BoolB, BoolC, BoolD FROM MyTable;
```

Into a bitmask, where the bits are defined by the values above.

For example, if `BoolA` and `BoolD` were true, I'd want `1001` or `9`.

I have something in mind to the effect of:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN BoolD THEN 2^0 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN BoolC THEN 2^1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN BoolB THEN 2^2 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN BoolA THEN 2^3 ELSE 0 END
FROM MyTable;
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach and seems rather verbose. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a bitmask, the type [**`bitstring`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) would be the better choice. Could look like this then:

```sql
SELECT BoolD::int::bit
    || BoolC::int::bit
    || BoolB::int::bit
    || BoolA::int::bit
FROM tbl;
```

`true` converts to `1`, `false` to `0`. You can simply concatenate bits to a bitstring.

#### Cast bit(n) to integer

It seems you need an `integer` as result - there is a simple & fast way:

```sql
SELECT (BoolD::int::bit
     || BoolC::int::bit
     || BoolB::int::bit
     || BoolA::int::bit)::bit(4)::int
FROM tbl;
```

Be sure to read the fine print in the chapter "[Bit String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html)" of the manual.

---

I came up with two more ideas and put together a quick test / reference with 10k rows to sum it all up.

Test setup:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (boola bool, boolb bool, boolc bool, boold bool);
INSERT INTO t
SELECT random()::int::bool
     , random()::int::bool
     , random()::int::bool
     , random()::int::bool
FROM   generate_series(1,10000);
```

Demo:

```sql
SELECT  CASE WHEN boold THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + (CASE WHEN boolc THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 1)
     + (CASE WHEN boolb THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 2)
     + (CASE WHEN boola THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 3) AS andriy

     ,  boold::int
     + (boolc::int << 1)
     + (boolb::int << 2)
     + (boola::int << 3) AS mike

     , (boola::int::bit
     || boolb::int::bit
     || boolc::int::bit
     || boold::int::bit)::bit(4)::int AS erwin1

     ,  boold::int
     | (boolc::int << 1)
     | (boolb::int << 2)
     | (boola::int << 3) AS erwin2

     , (((
       boola::int << 1)
     | boolb::int << 1)
     | boolc::int << 1)
     | boold::int        AS erwin3
FROM   t
LIMIT  15;
```

You could also use `|` (bitwise OR) instead of the `+` operator.
Individual test runs show basically the same performance for all five methods.

Comment: This approach would work, but from what I can tell, the Npgsql driver will convert a `bit varying` type into an array of booleans, which is not what I want.  Though I would need to try this to confirm, as I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: Just confirmed - Npgsql will convert `bit varying` into a string, that looks something like `"1001"` - So this approach, though probably valid for some scenarios, is not quite was I was looking for.

Comment: No, I wasn't *claiming*, but yes, I was indeed thinking of MySQL when offering my suggestion. And because of that, my initial assumption was actually correct. But I wasn't sure, and after Mike's reports that the idea wasn't working, I started thinking that `true` might *possibly* convert as `-1` in PostgreSQL, instead of `1` as in MySQL. It was later proved incorrect, so I eventually was reaffirmed in my initial guess. On the other note, I think your idea might work for Mike if you added conversion of the entire expression to `int`.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: See my amended answer for an integer solution.

Comment: @AndriyM: Fair enough, I rephrased my answer accordingly. Also, you were on the right track for a solution that fits Mike's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  Looks like there's all sorts of ways to do this, so it's just a matter of personal syntactic preference.

Comment: Very comprehensive! Would have upvoted this again if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT
  (CASE WHEN BoolA THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 0) +
  (CASE WHEN BoolB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 1) +
  (CASE WHEN BoolC THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 2) +
  (CASE WHEN BoolD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END << 3) AS BitMask
FROM MyTable;
```

where `<<` is the [`bitwise shift left`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-math.html) operator.

Comment: This results in the error `operator does not exist: boolean << integer`

Comment: If I do `BoolA::int` then the bitshift works, but for some reason it's not behaving like I'm expecting..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Oh, I see. I expected booleans were converted to integers implicitly in PostgreSQL. Too presumptuous of me, sorry. Edited my answer, which now doesn't differ from yours too much.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Re `BoolA::int` – possibly a boolean is converted to `int` as `-1`, not as `1`.

Comment: Ah I got it working.  It was an order of operation thing, I needed parentheses :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I think you should post your own answer and accept it!

Comment: You're probably right, but I'll give you an upvote for the bitshift idea :) I think the only way to make it less verbose is to wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this approach as well.  It's the most concise I could find short of writing a custom function.  I'll accept this answer unless anyone has anything more clever.

```
SELECT
  (BoolD::int << 0) +
  (BoolC::int << 1) +
  (BoolB::int << 2) +
  (BoolA::int << 3)
from MyTable;
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far. So you are right, if someone comes up with a better one, that would definitely deserve accepting.