# Is there any difference between integer and bit(n) data types for a bitmask?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, bitmask, postgresql-9.0

I am working with a table in a PostgreSQL database that has several boolean columns that determine some state (e.g. `published`, `visible`, etc.). I want to make a single status column that will store all these values as well as possible new ones in a form of a bitmask. Is there any difference between `integer` and `bit(n)` in this case?

This is going to be a rather big table, because it stores objects that users create via a web-interface. So I think I will have to use (partial) indexes for this column.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you only have **a few variables** I would consider keeping separate [**`boolean`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) columns.

- Indexing is easy. In particular also [indexes on expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) and [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).
- Conditions for queries are easy to write and read and meaningful.
- A boolean column occupies 1 byte (no alignment padding). For only a few variables this occupies the least space.
- Unlike other options `boolean` columns allow **`NULL`** values for individual bits if you should need that. You can always define columns `NOT NULL` if you don't.

If you have more than a hand full variables but **no more than 32**, an [**`integer`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) column *may* serve best. (Or a `bigint` for **up to 64** variables.)

- Occupies 4 bytes on disk (may require alignment padding, depending on     preceding columns).
- Very fast indexing for exact matches ( `=` operator).
- Handling individual values may be slower / less convenient than with `varbit` or `boolean`.

With even more variables, or if you want to manipulate the values a lot, or if you don't have huge tables or disk space / RAM is not an issue, or if you are not sure what to pick, I would consider [**`bit(n)`** or **`bit varying(n)`** (short: `varbit(n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html).

- Occupies at least 5 bytes (or 8 for very long strings) plus 1 byte for each group of 8 bits (rounded up).
- You can use [bit string functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html) directly, and [some standard SQL functions as well](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html).

For just **3 bits** of information, individual `boolean` columns get by with 3 bytes, an `integer` needs 4 bytes (maybe additional alignment padding) and a `bit string` 6 bytes (5 + 1).

For **32 bits** of information, an `integer` still needs 4 bytes (+ padding), a `bit string` occupies 9 bytes for the same (5 + 4) and `boolean` columns occupy 32 bytes.

To optimize **disk space** further you need to understand the storage mechanisms of PostgreSQL, especially data alignment. [More in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053568/939860) on how to **transform the types** `boolean`, `bit(n)` and `integer` may be of help, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, that is exactly what I needed! I think I will go with an `integer` column.

Comment: How can you use an integer serving several independent colums like bit?

Comment: @clarkk: In binary representation, an integer is a sequence of the allowed digits 0 and 1. (That's also how anything is stored in digital systems.) Each of these digits can be (ab-)used to store one independent, binary information. Basic mathematical operators can be used to read / write individual positions. (Postgres writes a new row version for any written change anyway, so barely any additional overhead.) Follow the [given link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053568/939860) for some basic techniques.

Answer (score 4):

With the advent of `GENERATED` columns in PostgreSQL (as from version 12), you could do something like this (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3_z5KXN7)):

Base table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  t_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  data TEXT,
  bitmask VARBIT(9)
);
```

but, with `GENERATED` columns, you can now do:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  t_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  data TEXT,
  bitmask VARBIT(9), -- choose 9 because it's not 8, to show that you don't have to 
                     -- select an INT or even a SMALLINT
  
  published   BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 0)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  visible     BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 1)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  rubbish     BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 2)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  masterpiece BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 3)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  meh         BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 4)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  arts        BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 5)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  legal       BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 6)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  sport       BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 7)::BOOLEAN) STORED,
  politics    BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GET_BIT(bitmask, 8)::BOOLEAN) STORED,

  
  
  CONSTRAINT subject_ck  -- so you can't have conflicting subjects - just for demo purposes
    CHECK                -- a document can't be art and legal at the same time!
    (
      CASE
        WHEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 5) = 1
          THEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 6) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 7) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 8) = 0

        WHEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 6) = 1
          THEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 5) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 7) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 8) = 0
  
        WHEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 7) = 1
          THEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 6) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 5) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 8) = 0

        WHEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 5) = 1
          THEN GET_BIT(bitmask, 8) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 7) = 0 AND GET_BIT(bitmask, 5) = 0
      END
    ) 
  
);
```

Now, the extra 9 booleans add about 12 bytes to the size of the table - if that isn't a problem, then we're good to go! Also, when (I presume shortly - as of writing 2022-09-09) PostgreSQL is enhanced with `VIRTUAL` columns, there'll be no space overhead at all.

The benefits of doing it like this is that it makes your SQL short and readable - instead of having to a bunch of ugly `CASE` statements, you'll simply be able to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO test (data, bitmask) VALUES
('Document 1', '000100000'),
('Document 2', '100000000'),
('Document 3', '101000001');
```

and also, stuff like this:

```
CREATE INDEX legal_ix ON test (legal) WHERE legal;
```

So now, obtaining all of the records is far easier on the eye -  much more legible:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

```
t_id    data    bitmask   published visible rubbish masterpiece meh arts    legal   sport   politics
1   Document 1  000100000         f       f       f           t   f    f        f       f         f
2   Document 2  100000000         t       f       f           f   f    f        f       f         f
3   Document 3  101000001         t       f       t           f   f    f        f       f         t
```

You can also do:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  -- can't update the other way round or CHECK constraint will fail
                    -- CHECK constraints are not deferrable - can't be 8 & 6 simultaneously
UPDATE test  
  SET bitmask = SET_BIT(bitmask, 8, 0) WHERE data = 'Document 3';
UPDATE test
  SET bitmask = SET_BIT(bitmask, 6, 1) WHERE data = 'Document 3';
COMMIT;
```

Result:

```
SELECT t_id, published, legal FROM test;  -- legal has gone from f -> t
```

There are a few other bits and pieces in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the [bit string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-bitstring.html) directly to a bit string without the need to cast from an integer.