# Handle multiple boolean items in a single row with postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, types, database-design

I have a table with more than 12 columns which just have boolean items! How to manage this with a single column?

And as part of requirement, this needs to be dynamic (in the sense, the column may increase in future) so it should act without altering the table!

Whats the best way to achieve this?

```
Table Users:
     married: False
     profession_provided: False
     location_provided: True
     certificates_provided: False
     exams_provided: True
```

Like the above i have more than 12 columns, and in near future this may increase - so is there any way to handle this - for example using Json or array or bitwise etc

I have read some article saying bitwise can be stored like this:

```
0010101
```

So if its 0 then false else true! Is this trustworthy or is there any effective way to handle this?

Comment: The "best way" very much depends on your definition of "good". Speed? Simplicity? Storage? ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of space-efficient solutions:

- [Is there any difference between integer and bit(n) data types for a bitmask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991476/is-there-any-difference-between-integer-and-bitn-data-types-for-a-bitmask/9993552#9993552)

An array of `boolean` (`bool[]`) would be another, still relatively space_efficient option.

If storage is of no concern, you might just add a document-type column ([`json`, `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html), or [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html)) to allow dynamic (schema-less) growth with more explicit storage of key and value.